# Automatically restart Python script in Windows

Tags: python, twitter

I wrote a Python script to use Twitter Stream API. Sometime error occurs and it stops streaming.

What can I do to make the script restart automatically? Is it something about bash?

I am not using Linux. Appreciate any solution for Windows. Thank you.

Comment: wrap your code around `try/except`

Answer (score 1):

You can either:

- Use loop to run your script:

Bash:

```
while true; do ./your_script.py; done
```

Windows CMD:

```
:loop

./your_script.py

goto loop
```

- Add a try/except to your main function and add a loop there:

```
def main():
    while True:
        try:
            your_logic()
        except:
            pass
```